# How can I return 401 Unauthorized from a custom authorizer in API Gateway without causing a Lambda error?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a custom authorizer for AWS Cognito using Node JS in Lambda and it works great.  It's basically using the code provided in [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/).

There are a number of ways my custom authorizer can fail: the user is using the wrong pool, the user submitted an invalid authorization token, etc.  Whenever this happens, I call:

```
      context.fail("Unauthorized");
```

and that works well too.

Unfortunately, when the user's token has expired (which happens all the time, especially first thing in the morning if somebody left their browser open), I also call that same method, which is the only way I know of to return a 401 message.  This works and the user is returned back to the login page.

The problem is that in my Cloudwatch dashboard, where we're monitoring for broken code / suspicious activity, every time somebody leaves their browser open we see a Lambda error.  This is very noisy and makes it hard to catch somebody doing something suspicious.

[image]

So my question: How can I fail the authorizer, return a 401 (or something else), not have the REST API execute and also NOT have an error show up in CloudWatch?

Comment: any solution found ?

Comment: Nope. But the more upvotes this gets, maybe AWS will notice.